# Blender 2.8 - fliping character pose in animation issue

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, keyframes, mirror

I don't know if this has been answered already.

I have a problem with Blender 2.8.

I have a character properly rigged and named.
I have started to create some animations like walk, idle, run etc..

My problem is when I want to flip the pose of the character it doesn't work.

In older versions of Blender I just pressed SHIFT+CTRL+V and it was fliped,but now when I press the same combination it doesn'T do anything.
So I have tried to flip the pose through the menu first in the editor window
(Pose -> Paste the pose fliped ) - pose isn't fliped, I have also tried to flip it through the Key menu (Key -> Paste flipped) in the action editor - doesn't work

This is the pose I want to flip.
[image]

And this the pose I get after pressing the Paste flipped/Paste the pose flipped
[image]

Does anybody knows what might be the problem ?

Comment: Hi! 
Just guessed: Does the bone-to-be-flipped has constrains, drivers or limits set for transformations? Is the name possibly misspelled like "Arm_L" "Arm_R " ?

Comment: Only constrains that I use are the IK system for the legs and copy rotations for fingers.Whole rig is named right (Arm.L,Arm.R etc...), I was using the same setup in older versions of BLender and everything worked.